# How to write five strings into one file

Tags: python, string, function

how to I collect multiple strings from each `print` as one function to write in another file?
(If I'm wording this right)

Heres is what I have:

```
 heart_max,heart_min = find_max_min (wanted_tuples, 0,1)
print ('Heart: {}  {:.1f}   {}   {:.1f}'.format(heart_min[1],heart_min[0],heart_max[1],heart_max[0]))

#
mv_max,mv_min = find_max_min (wanted_tuples, 0,2)
print ('Motor: {}  {:.1f} {}  {:.1f}'.format(mv_min[1],mv_min[0],mv_max[1],mv_max[0]))

#
birth_max,birth_min = find_max_min (wanted_tuples, 0,3)
print ('Birth:  {}   {:.1f}   {}  {:.1f}'.format(birth_min[1],birth_min[0],birth_max[1],birth_max[0]))

#
smoke_max,smoke_min = find_max_min (wanted_tuples, 0,4)
print ('Smoking: {}  {:.1f}   {}   {:.1f}'.format(smoke_min[1],smoke_min[0],smoke_max[1],smoke_max[0]))

#
ob_max,ob_min = find_max_min (wanted_tuples, 0,5)
print ('Obesity: {}   {:.1f}   {}   {:.1f}'.format(ob_min[1],ob_min[0],ob_max[1],ob_max[0])) 


outstring = {'Heart:'' {}  {:.1f}   {}  {:.1f}'.format(heart_min[1],heart_min[0],heart_max[1],heart_max[0])},
             'Motor:   {}  {:.1f}   {}  {:.1f}'.format(mv_min[1],mv_min[0],mv_max[1],mv_max[0])),
             'Birth:   {}  {:.1f}   {}  {:.1f}'.format(birth_min[1],birth_min[0],birth_max[1],birth_max[0])),
             'Smoking: {}  {:.1f}   {}  {:.1f}'.format(smoke_min[1],smoke_min[0],smoke_max[1],smoke_max[0])),
             'Obesity: {}  {:.1f}   {}  {:.1f}'.format(ob_min[1],ob_min[0],ob_max[1],ob_max[0]))}
```

Then write the results in this file

```
f_write = open('best_and_worst.txt', 'w') #creates the file
try:
    f_write.writelines(outstring)

finally:
        f_write.close()
```

I formatted the string like this so that I can make the output look like this when ran:

```
                                       Min                          Max 
Heart:        Minnesota                1.8          Missouri        26.4
Motor:        Washington               2.8          Colorado        34.6
Birth:        Ohio                     4.4          New York        43.2
Smoking:      Utah                     6.1          Ohio            44.3
Obesity:      Michigan                19.1          Mississippi     37.3
```

I entire long program runs fine without errors. Its just for some reason I draw a blank on how to do this. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `print()`, just store the strings in a list and write the strings to your file:

```
output = []

heart_max,heart_min = find_max_min (wanted_tuples, 0,1)
output.append('Heart: {}  {:.1f}   {}   {:.1f}'.format(heart_min[1],heart_min[0],heart_max[1],heart_max[0]))

mv_max,mv_min = find_max_min (wanted_tuples, 0,2)
output.append('Motor: {}  {:.1f} {}  {:.1f}'.format(mv_min[1],mv_min[0],mv_max[1],mv_max[0]))

# etc.

with open('best_and_worst.txt', 'w') as f_write:
    f_write.write('\n'.join(output))
```

Comment: Actually I would have thought, that this (no postprocessing, but simply buffering the output) is exactly the problem, which StringIO module was designed to address, which has at least a chance to require less memory overhead - no?

Comment: @guidot: You could also just write straight to the file. In this case, a StringIO instance is not going to save on memory.